# Session management using nodeJS without a session store

Tags: node.js, session, session-management

im fairly  new to MEAN stack development. I've developed a site as a project im working on using only node, express, angular and mongo. Ive gotten the login, register and logout web service calls to work perfectly but having a difficult time to manage the session.

When the user refreshes the page he gets logged out. this is my server.js code which uses session
`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
 app.use(cookieParser());
 app.use(session({resave: true, saveUninitialized: true, secret: 'secret',cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));`

and on login i also perform the following code if the login is a success.

```
router.get('/success', function(req, res){
    req.session.cookie.lastLogin = new Date().getTime();
    req.session.name = req.user.name;
    req.session.username = req.user.email;
    res.send({status: 200,state: 'success', user: req.user ? req.user : null});
});
```

the response has all the details like user info and if i pass the sessions object in 'req' that also returns with accurate info.

on log out, i execute the following code:

```
router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.session.destroy();
    req.logout();
    console.log("user logged out.log out called and session.destroy() called.");
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

What im having trouble with is making sure and validating whether the using is still logged in after page refresh and navigation to other pages.
Any help on this matter would be great ! im sorry if this a repeat of an existing question. Ive been breaking my head and i think im close to a solution but cant fine tune it.

EDIT :
i also wrote an api to keep the session alive.

```
router.post('/keepSessionAlive', function(req, res){
    if(typeof req.cookies['connect.sid'] != 'undefined') {
        console.log(req.cookies['connect.sid']+":: user is :"+req.session.username);
        res.send({status: 200,state: 'success', user: req.session ? req.session : null});
    }else{
        req.logout();
        console.log("user logged out. aaw not alive");
        res.send({status: 500,state: 'failure', message:"something went wrong. For" +req});
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using express-session?  If so, there is a session store.  The default is a memory-based store so I don't really understand why you're asking a question about session management without a store.  Usually, the whole point of using a session is so you can have user state associated with their session which requires some sort of store, even if it's in-memory.

Comment: well, when i meant no session store i meant, i didnt use any specific one like connect-mongo, which means i would be using the default store.

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the cooke with every request?

Comment: For the default store, I think you have to explicitly call `req.session.save()` after you modify the session object.  Yes, I know one would think that `resave: true` should make it so that isn't necessary, but I think I recall in my prior testing that things only worked when I added `req.session.save()` to my code after modifying the session object.

Comment: Wouldnt the cookie be sent on every request ? and req.session.save() can only be used with some kind of session-store right? it wouldnt work on the default store